# Mailgun ignores CC/BCC by curl

Tags: php, laravel, curl, mailgun, laravel-6

So this is the code.

```
define('MAILGUN_URL', '--domain--');
define('MAILGUN_KEY', '--key--');
$array_data = array(
                'from' => 'from',
                'to' => [$email, $cc],
                'cc' => $cc,
                'bcc' => $cc,
                'subject' => '--subject--',
                'html' => $html,
                'text' =>  'test',
                'o:tracking' => 'no',
                'o:tracking-clicks' => 'no',
                'o:tracking-opens' => 'no',
            );

$session = curl_init(MAILGUN_URL . '/messages');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'api:' . MAILGUN_KEY);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array_data);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$response = curl_exec($session);

curl_close($session);
```

I tried with every possible way, it seems like it just ignores the field $cc, also tried directly having the email between " ", only sends email to the first "to".

Comment: Does it ignore the CC field on the to field, or on the cc field? You're including the `$cc` on all 3 fields, so it may only seem to add it to one. For multiple address in the To field, the [documentation](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-sending.html#sending) says `You can use commas to separate multiple recipients.`

Comment: @aynber it ignores it anywhere, posted it like this to show that I tried everything.

Comment: Try CC and BCC to 2 different addresses, maybe it is actually spotting you are using the same email address for all 3 options and removing the CC and BCC as unnecessary

Comment: Even if i only have to and separate 'cc', it ignores the variable in the $cc // "email@email.com".

Comment: @RiggsFolly just tried - still no luck. tried a personal and a gmail.

Comment: You may need to contact Mailgun, if it's not sending to all addresses that you've supplied.